# How to select label for="XYZ" in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

```css
label {
  display: block;
  width: 156px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-right: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<label for="email">{t _your_email}:</label>
```

I wish to select the label based on the `'for'` attribute to make layout changes.

Answer (score 591, accepted):

The selector would be `label[for=email]`, so in CSS:

```
label[for=email]
{
    /* ...definitions here... */
}
```

...or in JavaScript using the DOM:

```
var element = document.querySelector("label[for=email]");
```

...or in JavaScript using jQuery:

```
var element = $("label[for=email]");
```

It's an [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#attribute-selectors). Note that some browsers (versions of IE < 8, for instance) may not support attribute selectors, but more recent ones do. To support older browsers like IE6 and IE7, you'd have to use a class (well, or some other structural way), sadly.

(I'm assuming that the template `{t _your_email}` will fill in a field with `id="email"`. If not, use a class instead.)

Note that if the value of the attribute you're selecting doesn't fit the rules for a [CSS identifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) (for instance, if it has spaces or brackets in it, or starts with a digit, etc.), you need quotes around the value:

```
label[for="field[]"]
{
    /* ...definitions here... */
}
```

They [can be single or double quotes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#strings).

Comment: I'll change it to a class for ie7 using conditiona comments then, thanks for the great answer!

Comment: And now the jQuery docs say you don't need the quotes for single words, so it matches CSS again (in this regard).

Comment: To avoid confusion to everyone (I just had this myself), there must be no space between `label` and `[for=email]`

Comment: IE8 does support attribute selectors as long as the page has a <!DOCTYPE> declared.

Comment: @ilinamorato: I didn't say it didn't. I said versions **`<`** 8 may not.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I understand.  I was only clarifying the point as I just tested it.

Comment: Update for modern JavaScript: `document.querySelector('label[for="email"]')` or `document.querySelectorAll('label[for="email"]')`.

Comment: @Manngo - `querySelector` is literally the second code block above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Manngo's example has quotes around the attribute value while your answer does not. At least for me, in a JSDom environment, it only works with quotes. Thanks Manngo! [edit] I see you call out the potential need for quotes at the bottom of your answer. I missed that [/edit]

Comment: @IGx89 - See the paragraph in the answer saying *"Note that if the value of the attribute you're selecting doesn't fit the rules for a CSS identifier..."* and providing a spec link for when you do and don't need them. (Or always use them if you prefer.)

Answer (score 0):

If the content is a variable, it will be necessary to concatenate it with quotation marks. It worked for me. Like this:

```
itemSelected(id: number){
    console.log('label contains', document.querySelector("label[for='" + id + "']"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `label` **immediately** follows a specified `input` element:

```
input#example + label { ... }
input:checked + label { ... }
```