# CSS selectors - how to select 'for' in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm using jQuery validation.

When for is now valid, validator is creating those:

```
<label class="error" for="username" generated="true">
```

As all label has got the same **class=error** can I select with CSS this exact one based on **'for'**?

I know how to sort this out with jQuery - but always looking for cleanest, purest way.
Any suggestion much appreciated.

Pete

Comment: if you are producing unique label elements, wouldent it be suitable to attach some unique id's to each label for jquery selections?

Comment: @john - 'inputs' do have unique ID - but jQuery Validator do not copy them over - I could call them(inputs with ID) by jQUery, than find next element and add class to it(another unique class to label with class error)- but this was not the point of my question. I'm looking for pure css solution.

Comment: @jAndy - This is inhouse project - only Chrome & only me.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599627/how-to-select-label-for-email-in-css

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using the (CSS2) [attribute selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/attributeselector):

```
.error[for="username"]
```

This will work in IE8+ and all modern browsers.

---

IE7's attribute selector is buggy: [as explained here](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/03/08/ie7-attribute-selector-bugs/#enter-ie7), to match `for`  you must use `htmlFor`.

So, if you need IE7 support, use this:

```
.error[for="username"], .error[htmlFor="username"]
```

Comment: Just make sure I understand what that URL reference is trying to say -- it's the fact that "for" is a keyword that makes IE7 fail, correct? If you use something like .error[foo='bar'] it would match <div class="error" foo="bar"></div> as expected?

Answer (score 5):

Any attribute can be selected with CSS or jQuery using the `[]` notation. CSS applies to any XML-like syntax, not just HTML -- it doesn't know (or care) what attributes are "valid" as long as the structure is well-formed.

```
.error[for='username'] {

}
```

or for a "starts with"

```
.error[for^='userprefix'] {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the css:

```
.error[for=username] {
}
```

In the jQuery

```
$('.error[for=username]')
```

Comment: I believe jQuery 1.6 requires quotes around attribute values.