# CSS target label based on for attribute?

Tags: css, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS selectors - how to select ‘for’ in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535274/css-selectors-how-to-select-for-in-css)

I have the following html. Can I target the label based on its for attribute (so only target this label)?

```
<label for="something">Text</label>
```

Comment: And just as I answer the question, I find a duplicate. One that I've voted on at that...

Comment: While this is a duplicate, I think the votes speak for themselves: this question is worded better.

Comment: Dulpicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599627/how-to-select-label-for-email-in-css

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can target the attribute by :

```
label[for="something"] {
   /* woohoo! */
}
```

**For** stands for the attribute name
and **="value"** stands for its value.