# How to add specific classes that will get used only specific lebel name given earlier?

Tags: css

I have this code:

```
<label class="control-label" for="atr17">Υπηρεσίες</label>
<div class="controls"><ul class="atr-ul atr-ul-checkbox"><li><div class="atr-input-box atr-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="atr_17_126" name="atr_17_126" wtx-context="2860570E-16D9-45EA-89B2-87BD0DD0DDEC"> <label for="atr_17_126">test1</label></div></li><li><div class="atr-input-box atr-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="atr_17_127" name="atr_17_127" wtx-context="3B096793-B59B-40C6-858C-45AA49C91033"> <label for="atr_17_127">test2</label></div></li><a href="#" class="atr-select-deselect atr-select-all">Select all</a><a href="#" class="atr-select-deselect atr-deselect-all" style="display:none;">Deselect all</a></ul></div>
```

normally this  `<li>`

is managed with this css:
`.post-edit #atr-form ul.atr-ul li { css here }`

But i want somehow to manage the css of these

based on the label "atr17" that i given on top. How can i do this?

Thank you?

i tried to play with something like that
`label[for=atr17] { width: 30% !important; }`

also tried:
`label[for=atr17] { li { width: 30% !important; } }`

but didn't work

Its not a duplicate question since i dont want to add css to the label. I want to add css to li followed after this label name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS target label based on for attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935064/css-target-label-based-on-for-attribute)

Comment: no it doesnt answer because i dont want to apply css to the label. I want apply css to the <li> that followed the for="atr17"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all of the `li` that follow a specific `label` using the [adjacent sibling selector (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator).

```css
label[for="atr17"] + .controls li { 
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<label class="control-label" for="atr17">Υπηρεσίες</label>
<div class="controls">
  <ul class="atr-ul atr-ul-checkbox">
    <li>
      <div class="atr-input-box atr-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="atr_17_126" name="atr_17_126" wtx-context="2860570E-16D9-45EA-89B2-87BD0DD0DDEC"> 
        <label for="atr_17_126">test1</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="atr-input-box atr-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="atr_17_127" name="atr_17_127" wtx-context="3B096793-B59B-40C6-858C-45AA49C91033"> 
        <label for="atr_17_127">test2</label>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" class="atr-select-deselect atr-select-all">Select all</a>
  <a href="#" class="atr-select-deselect atr-deselect-all" style="display:none;">Deselect all</a>
</div>
```