# How to select "label for=list[]" in CSS?

Tags: css

I have an array of check boxes and `jquery validate` plugin applies the label with `class error` like this,

```
<label for="list[]" class="error">This field is required.</label>
```

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599627/how-to-select-label-for-email-in-css) answer but when i changed it to `label[for=list[]]` it didn't work. How can i select it using css?

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xtmMJ/1/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use quotes around the value. In this case `"list[]"`.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vYyL9/)

```
[for="list[]"]{
    color:red;
}
```

For more information, check out the [documentation on attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors).