# How to hide <label for=""> CSS

Tags: css, label, hide

I am trying to hide these:

```
<p>
<label for="secondname"><?php esc_html_e('Last Name','wpestate');?></label>
<input type="text" id="secondname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $last_name;?>"  name="firstname">
</p>
```

I managed to hide the Input, but not the label.

```
#secondname {
  display: none;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select label for="email" in CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599627/how-to-select-label-for-email-in-css)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
label[for="secondname"]
{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: This is not recommended for accessibility reason. Check this answer pointing on the W3C suggestion to visibly hide a label https://stackoverflow.com/a/75419659/6911151

Answer (score 11):

Hiding the label with `display: none;` is bad for web accesibility and you shouldn't do it.
Try `visibility: hidden;` instead.

Comment: yep, why I added a `label` I didn't want to see in the first place. `display: block; height: 0; visibility: hidden;`. visibility hidden isn't necessary with height of `0`.. but good to know it's not supposed to be shown. display has to be block for height to be set to 0 and not affect layout. width could probably use a `0` too, but didn't matter in my case.

Comment: `visibility: hidden` is bad for a11y as well (`height: 0` too)
Good read & advice at: https://www.scottohara.me/blog/2017/04/14/inclusively-hidden.html

Answer (score 10):

Use the [attribute selector](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp):

```
label[for="secondname"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `label[for="secondname"] { display: none }`

Answer (score 2):

Why include the label at all if its hidden?  display: none; will hide it from screen readers and most anything else.

Instead, position it off screen:

```
label[for="secondname"]
{
    position: absolute !important;
    width: 1px !important;
    height: 1px !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
    white-space: nowrap !important;
    border: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be the recommendation from W3C docs:

'*Screen readers and other assistive technology, just as web browsers, hide elements from their user when they are styles using display: none; and visibility: hidden;.*'.
[https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/#:~:text=The%20label%20can%20be%20hidden,reader%20and%20speech%20input%20users](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/#:%7E:text=The%20label%20can%20be%20hidden,reader%20and%20speech%20input%20users).

```
.visuallyhidden {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much!
This solution worked for me:

```html
label[for="secondname"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: It's nice to thank people for their answers but it'd be better to comment under their answers than duplicating their answers.