# Select a label with CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors, label, code-snippets

I already found threads about this topic like these:

[How to hide <label for=""> CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40029976/how-to-hide-label-for-css)

[How to select label for="XYZ" in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599627/how-to-select-label-for-xyz-in-css)

So I thought it's going to be easy, but for now I had no success.

The label I try to reach is this one:

Inside of code snippets I tried the following:

label[for=payment_method_angelleye_ppcp]

.label[for=payment_method_angelleye_ppcp]

label[for="payment_method_angelleye_ppcp"]

.label[for="payment_method_angelleye_ppcp"]

After a couple of Google sessions, I wasn't able to find any other way of writing. It also seems that you don't set a "." in front of it for this case, but I also tried it, of course.

I believe label[for="name"] is the correct format in general...

But it seems something is missing. Inside the label there is a text and an image, but I don't assume that this plays a role in selecting the label?

Comment: Could you add a HTML snippet? You can read more about: [example]

Answer (score 0):

I put one in CSS and 1 in javascript

```js
document.querySelector('label[for="ABC"]').style.color = 'blue';
```

```css
label[for="XYZ"] {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<label for="XYZ">XYZ: </label>
<input id="XYZ">

<label for="ABC">XYZ: </label>
<input id="ABC">
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort and solution! I also tried to address the label with your provided javascript but somehow its without an effect. I do wonder if it has something to do with the fact that I try to do this with the wordpress plugin codesnippets. May I will reach out to the plugin support to find this out. In any case its weird because it should work

Comment: if you need the CSS try the magic (awful) important! perhaps it'll override another css property of your label (if the other not also important and arriving after yours). "color: red !important;"

Comment: I already tried. I will play around a bit more and see how I get this going. If I find a way that works I will update this thread of course :)

Comment: in dev tools, try to check which class is killing yours

Comment: Yes! I got this tipp as well yesterday "In such cases, you can try by increasing the specificity of the declaration, by adding the id or the class of the form or other parent element. " I will try to figure how to do this and will reply afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Pierre's answer is good, I just want to clarify that label is [an HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label). Unless you have a CSS class "label", you would not be adding a period in front of the selector in CSS.
You're correct, the content (images and text) inside of a label will not affect the selector we're trying to use but there may be other CSS interfering with what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! Especially about the usage of a period in this case!