# How to change the color of a label that's in a `<ul>` and `<li>`

Tags: html, css, list, label

I would really like to know how I can change the `font-color` of a specific `<label>` having attribute `for="shipping_method_0_774"` while it's in an unordered list and a list item...

```html
   <ul id="shipping_method" class="woocommerce-shipping-methods">
<li>
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_774" value="774" class="shipping_method">
    <label for="shipping_method_0_774">Pakketpost Bezorging: GRATIS</label> 
</li>
</ul>
```

Would really like you help!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select label for="XYZ" in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599627/how-to-select-label-for-xyz-in-css)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`[]`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) to set your wanted attribute

```css
ul li label[for="shipping_method_0_774"]{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="shipping_method" class="woocommerce-shipping-methods">
  <li>
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_774" value="774" class="shipping_method"><label for="shipping_method_0_774">Pakketpost Bezorging: GRATIS</label> </li>
</ul>
```

To be more spesific for current `ul` (with id) use:

```
#shipping_method li label[for="shipping_method_0_774"]{
color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```css
label[for="shipping_method_0_774"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label for="shipping_method_0_774">Correct label</label>

<br>

<label for="shipping_method_1337">Random label</label>
```