# Set css style for a lable with different ID's

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

Based on that [How to select label for="XYZ" in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599627/how-to-select-label-for-xyz-in-css) question I have a more detailed question.

We have a form where we can enter the recipient email address.
This is how the HTML looks like:

```
<label for="recipient_email[0]">Text</label>
```

We know that we can select that specific label field with that CSS:

```
label[for="recipient_email[0]"] {
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

**Problem:**
Then a ID is added to that label field. This ID is always changing and therefor the CSS above does not work anymore. Is there a hack we can use for that problem?

```
<label for="recipient_email[fdb450312833afa7e5c9faf377e4f872]">Text</label>
```

Cheers

Comment: if you want to style only this specific label more context is needed, for example, what's the ID or classes of its container tag?, is this container a div or a form?, hence the CSS selector to use

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this selector does not exist, you can use an `id` for each label, for example:

```
<label id="label1" for="recipient_email[0]">Text</label>
<label id="label2" for="recipient_email[1]">Text</label>
<label id="label3" for="recipient_email[2]">Text</label>
```

Comment: the problem is this is from a plugin, I can not change the html structure :(